# In a work e-mail, what is the correct way to refer to one's wife who is a coworker?

Tags: keigo, business-japanese

## Japanese

## 背景

今年度、私の妻は就職できました。今年の4月から、2人とも同じ職場で大学の教員として勤めています。というわけで今回の質問です。就職時に色々な事務手続きをしなければなりません。その中で、私は事務担当者にメールを作成中です。メールの相手先は事務担当者ですが、妻にもCCしています。

## 質問

職場で、自分の配偶者をメールでどのように呼ぶのが丁寧でしょうか。

身内に対して「X先生」を使うのは大丈夫ですか。それとも、それは「身内か外部の人か」のパターンに関係する失礼な言い方にあたりますか。どの呼び方を使用するのが一番丁寧ですか。

## English

## Background

This year, my wife started working here in Japan. From this April, we are both university instructors. And that leads to this question. There's all sorts of paperwork for her starting work, and in the process I was e-mailing one of the administrative staff and copied my wife on the e-mail.

## Question

At work, what is the correct way to address one's own spouse in e-mails?

Is it okay in a work context to refer to one's spouse as X先生? Or is that inappropriate due to the in-group / out-group patterns. What is the most appropriate way to refer?

Comment: @narutoさん　非常にありがたいです。いつもお世話になっております。

Comment: 私の大学にも、奥さんが同じ大学で教えている教授がいますが、奥さんのことを「XX先生」と呼んでるのは見たことないです。（学生さんの前では「XX先生」と呼ばれますが。）

Comment: @Chocolate そうですか。私たちは学生の前にいつも名字で呼ばれてほしいで、教授もその風に呼ばれていますが、事務担当者に名前を使ったことはないです。

Comment: 私学共済に加入するとか、健康保険や年金や税金に関する手続きをするために、人事課か経理部の事務とメールなどでやり取りする場合の話ですかね？そういう場合はやっぱり「家内」とか「妻」とか名前（「さん」をつけないで）で呼ぶほうがいいと思いますが。「家内の住民票の写しです。」とか「花子の住民票の写しです。」とか。逆にお「山田花子先生の住民票の写しです。」とかいうと変ですよね・・

Comment: その通りです。実は文部科学省共済ですが、書類はあまり変わらないと感じます。

Comment: ならば、@Chocolateさんは 以下の答えと賛成していないでしょうか。

Comment: @virmaior 他の方のコメントを見て私の回答がピント外れであることがわかりました。「質問　職場で、自分の配偶者をメールでどのように呼ぶのが丁寧でしょうか。」これが原因です。「質問　配偶者と共働きの職場の事務手続きで送るメールで自分の配偶者をどう書くのが適切ですか。このメールは配偶者にもCCしております」として回答します。メール本文では、「妻」「家内」あるいは「妻＊＊＊＊（姓名）」（但し「家内＊＊＊＊（姓名）はダメ」）でしょう。CCは奥様の姓名（敬称なし）がよいと思います。

Comment: ＠virmaior 教師として奥さんを扱うときは、他の先生方に対して表現する方法と同じ表現が良いと思います。私のAnswerはそのつもりで書きました。

Comment: 了解です。「cc: 苗字名前」にするのは間違いと思った方がいいでしょうか。また「cc: 妻苗字名前」でもいいですか。

Comment: cc:苗字名前とcc:姓名とは同じ意味で書きました。cc:妻苗字名前は駄目です。第三者に妻であることを明示したいときはCC: 苗字名前（妻）なら、良いでしょう。

Comment: はい、わかりました！そのように今後かきます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「X先生」を使うのが大丈夫ですか。

職場｛しょくば｝（大学｛だいがく｝内｛ない｝）で、他｛た｝の教員｛きょういん｝に使｛つか｝う呼称｛こしょう｝と同｛おな｝じで構｛かま｝いません。
奥｛おく｝さん以外｛いがい｝の学内｛がくない｝の教員｛きょういん｝にメールで「＊＊＊先生｛せんせい｝」と宛名｛あてな｝を書｛か｝くなら、奥｛おく｝さんにも「〇〇〇 先生｛せんせい｝」と書｛か｝いてください。

ところで、質問者｛しつもん｝と奥様｛おくさま｝は苗字｛みょうじ｝/名字｛みょうじ｝が同｛おな｝じでしょうから、質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝であるあなたと奥様｛おくさま｝とを職場｛しょくば｝で区別｛くべつ｝するために姓｛せい｝・名｛めい｝を書｛か｝く必要｛ひつよう｝があります。

日本｛にほん｝での一｛ひと｝つの習慣｛しゅうかん｝で、苗字｛みょうじ｝が同｛おな｝じで別人｛べつじん｝を区別｛くべつ｝するために、姓名｛せいめい｝全部｛ぜんぶ｝を書｛か｝くのでなく、名｛めい｝の部分｛ぶぶん｝を次｛つぎ｝のように省略｛しょうりゃく｝して区別｛くべつ｝する場合｛ばあい｝も普通｛ふつう｝に実施｛じっし｝されています。

> 鈴木 妙子、　鈴木 和夫　→　鈴木（妙）、鈴木（和）